# Qgis PyQT app error:

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt

Can somebody help me.
Trying to run Qgis PyQT app, but have an error in command line

---

```
C:\work\2q5>python program.py
C:\src\qgis\src\core\qgscoordinatereferencesystem.cpp(472) : (QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::loadFromDatabase) [0ms] failed : /resources/srs.db does not exist!
C:\src\qgis\src\gui\qgsmapcanvas.cpp(466) : (QgsMapCanvas::refresh) [15ms] CANVAS refresh - invalid settings -> nothing to do
C:\src\qgis\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(89) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [125ms] Checking  for provider plugins
C:\src\qgis\src\core\qgsmessagelog.cpp(33) : (QgsMessageLog::logMessage) [0ms] 2017-04-23T15:16:04 No Data Providers[1] No QGIS data provider plugins found in:

No vector layers can be loaded. Check your QGIS installation
C:\src\qgis\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(377) : (QgsProviderRegistry::provider) [0ms] Library name is
C:\src\qgis\src\core\qgsmessagelog.cpp(33) : (QgsMessageLog::logMessage) [16ms]
2017-04-23T15:16:04 [1] Failed to load : The shared library was not found.
C:\src\qgis\src\core\qgsvectorlayer.cpp(1499) : (QgsVectorLayer::setDataProvider) [62ms]  unable to get data provider
```

I set this enviroment vars like this

```
C:\work\2q5>set PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\lib;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python36;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python36\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem
C:\work\2q5>set GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal
C:\work\2q5>set GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins
C:\work\2q5>set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
C:\work\2q5>set GEOTIFF_CSV=C:\OSGeo4W\share\epsg_csv
C:\work\2q5>set GISBASE=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0
C:\work\2q5>set GRASS_PROJSHARE=C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj
C:\work\2q5>set GRASS_PYTHON=C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python.exe
C:\work\2q5>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
C:\work\2q5>set PROJ_LIB=C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj
C:\work\2q5>set PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python36
C:\work\2q5>set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev
C:\work\2q5>set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\qtplugins;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt5\plugins

C:\work\2q5>set  QGIS_PROVIDER_FILE=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\plugins
```

In the QGIS_PROVIDER_FILE directory i have grassprovider7.dll, ogrprovider.dll and else dll`s.
Starting command line from OSGeo4W Shell and rewriting this env vars.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! 
    set QGIS_PROVIDER_FILE=provider.dll

Qgis instance searching data providers dll`s by the mask *QGIS_PROVIDER_FILE*.
QGIS_PROVIDER_FILE is substring of its file name.